# Define a new olap datasource with Pentaho 5.0 CE

Tags: pentaho

With Pentaho v4.x we can define new olap datasource in the file `pentaho-solutions/system/olap/datasources.xml`, but this file is missing in Pentaho 5.0 CE.
How can I define new a olap datasource with Pentaho 5.0 CE?

The Pentaho documentation is not very helpful, they talk about a [migration tool](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fupgrade_guide%2Fconcept_prepare_upgrade_plan.html) but I can't find a link to download it.

Some users on the Pentaho forum have similar questions, but no answer are given.

- http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?153855-In-version-5-0-1-pentaho-solutions-system-olap-datasources-xml-missing
- http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?156929-DSP-In-pentaho-5-0-2

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define olap datasources in 5.0 using the manage Data Sources Functionality.

If you create a new Analysis Data Source, you'll be prompted for a schema file (the mondrian cube definition) that you can upload.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can upload with the help of 
Manage datasource -->setting button (Next to new data source) -- >analysis -->Select you file .

You can pass parameter mannually if you are using DynamicSchemaProcessor.